# swagger codegen maven overwriting generated file with same name but different case

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin version 2.2.1 to generate stubs using yaml file. I am facing issue here. when i try to generate class with Same name but different case only one file is present in the generated folder.
I have below 2 Objects:

1. OtherFlightInformation
2. OtherflightInformation

Only difference is alphabet "F" in flight(in one its capital in another its small).

In the generated folder i can see only file OtherFlightInformation.java but OtherflightInformation.java file is missing

I can see in the logs that file is getting written but in the folder its missing.
[image]

Is there any configuration I have to do so that both the files are present.

Comment: Windows file names are _case-insensitive_. You can't have those two files!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose.. Thanks a lot for the comment. That saved my day :)
Can you put it in the answer section so that i can mark it as solved